# splitting or tokenize comma with space and comma[JAVA]

Tags: java, split, tokenize

January 22, 2014

I want to split the string into three but the second has , and space

Comment: Split it once, then split it again...or remove the comma...

Comment: @MadProgrammer what || means in regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you, you could use a single (zero or one matches) regular expression with something like -

```
String in = "January 22, 2014";
String[] arr = in.split(",?\\ ");
for (String str : arr) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Output is

```
January
22
2014
```

Comment: Maybe “zero or one” (`?`) would be more appropriate here?

Comment: how can i store that to three strings? will it worked if the date is from the user?

Comment: @5gon12eder Agreed. That's better. Edited.

Comment: @dumas It is three strings. `arr[0]`, `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`. Yes, as long as it's one space or one comma and one space between fields. You could conceivably want ",?\\s+" which would eat all consecutive white space.